# Tab index not working in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabindex

I have used this plugin: http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

to customize all the select tag in my website, as you can see in this way the `select` tags are not visible and not display, they are replaced by a div `<div class="select-styled"></div>` where any value selected of the option is inserted. I like the simplicity of this code but i would like to give the possibility to the user to use the tab when he fills out the form. 
Obviously in this case any it's not possible because the `select` tags are hidden so they are skipped by the tab button.

I have reproduced the case here http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/ciFtv where i have inserted an input before and after the `select` tags and as you can see the tab button only works between the `inputs` . So my question is , how can i solve this problem? how can i add the `tabindex` which let me also using the `select` in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put explicit tabindex attributes on your select form elements, such as:

```
<select id="mounth" tabindex="2">
```

In your script, in the $('select').each(function(){...

Add this:

```
tabIndex = $this.attr('tabindex');
```

And modify the line where you insert the styled div version to include the tabindex attribute with the original tabindex number that you have captured with tabIndex:

```
$this.after('<div class="select-styled" tabindex='+ tabIndex +'></div>');
```

That should give you what you want.

(Here's a revised page of your codepen page with it in action:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIeHd )

Answer (score 1):

Give the first item an index of 1 like so:

```
<input class="string required" tabindex='1' id="account_last_name" name="account[last_name]" required="required" size="50" type="text" />
```

Add a counter to your each statment like so:

```
$('select').each(function(i){/*code*/}
```

Add the counter+1 to the tab index of the dynamic div like so:

```
$this.after('<div tabindex='+(i+1)+' class="select-styled"></div>');
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CzlGH)**